# Modx дополнительные поля

Tags: php, cms, modx, шаблоны

В Modx дополнительные поля привязываются к шаблонам. У меня в проекте много ресурсов для которых нужно добавить разные дополнительные поля. При этом оформление на всех страницах(шапка, подвал) одинаковые. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли в такой ситуации делать много шаблонов, с одинаковым оформлением, только для того, что бы для разных ресурсов задать разные дополнительные поля? Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться **"Настройкой форм"**.

Например, у нас есть структура:

```
- Телефоны (10)
  - Телефон 1
  - Телнфон 2
- Холодильники (20)
  - Холодильник 1
  ...
```

У телефонов и холодильников один шаблон, например **ProductTpl**. Идём в "Настройки форм", создаём профиль (делаем активным), затем редактируем его (правой кнопкой), ставим *группу пользователей* и создаём *новый набор правил*.

Выбираем нужное действие, ставим шаблон (в нашем случаи ProductTpl) и указываем `Ограничивающее поле: parent` и `Ограничивающее значение: 10 (10 - id группы с телефонами)`.

После создания правила мы можем его отредактировать и во вкладке `Дополнительные поля` убрать галочки с тех `tv`, которые не требуется выводить в этой категории.

Для другой группы ресурсов будет соответственно своё правило со своим набором `tv`, которые требуется выводить.